# Intellij takes forever to execute maven goals for a JUnit test

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, build

I'm running a Junit test and everytime I run it, I wait ~5 minutes for "executing maven goals". After that it starts up application context and runs tests. I know that this same test runs without executing maven goals and a lot faster on other environments.

I tried removing "*Build*" from configuration...
[image]

... but then it doesn't update changed files

Here is how it looks in IntelliJ (for my 5 minutes):
[image]

I suppose Build takes too long in my case, is there any other way to grab the changes before running the test and not wait forever?

Comment: It looks like you've set IntelliJ IDEA to run some Maven goal before starting the tests. Check it in the [Maven projects tool window](https://i.imgur.com/MzBE13G.png). Also try disabling the [Maven build/run delegation option](https://i.imgur.com/QKGIrbG.png).

Comment: Turns out I had "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven", disabling it solved the problem. Now it doesn't build entire project for a single change. Thanks @CrazyCoder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the [Maven build/run delegation option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsark.png) in File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner.